# Realm where with Date return null

Tags: java, android, realm

Here is my Realm database
[image]

Here is my code for find value with **where** and **equalTo**, when I use `int` it working, and if I use `Date` it not working.
You will see in the image below, `realmNumber` return value, and `realmDate` return null
[image]

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(final Realm bgRealm) {

        StepEntry realmNumber = bgRealm.where(StepEntry.class).equalTo("steps", 0).findFirst();

        Date date = stepEntry.getDate();
        StepEntry realmDate = bgRealm.where(StepEntry.class).equalTo("date", date).findFirst();
    }
});
```

How can I make `Realm` where work with `Date`

Comment: Date comparision is supported in realm by default. Are you sure that there exists at least StepEntry instance in realm in which "date" is exactly same to the millisecond as the `stepEntry.getDate()` you're passing in `where`?

Comment: yes, I see Realm support `Date` type. @Tushar please see 2 images you will see 2 days is same

Comment: They might not be equal on the millisecond. Milliseconds are not printed as part of `Date.toString()`. You need to verify that `date1.getTime() == date2.getTime()`.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior what is date1 and date2, how can I use `equalTo` with `date`

Comment: `equalTo` already work with date: https://realm.io/docs/java/2.2.0/api/io/realm/RealmQuery.html#equalTo-java.lang.String-java.util.Date- . `date1/date2` is just two different dates.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior How can I know my realm database contain a row that have a date column equals my input date? Like you explain we can not do it with Realm

Comment: Please read what I and others already wrote. You can do it with Realm, but if the data object you search for doesn't match exactly (down to milliseconds), it will not find anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128330/discussion-between-phan-van-linh-and-christian-melchior).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot find your object with equalTo(field, Date) then that means the Date you provide in the condition does not match.

Realm has milisecond precision since 0.90.0, so your Date must match in terms of hours, minutes, seconds, miliseconds (technically the long epoch time value must be the exact same)

```
StepEntry realmDate = bgRealm.where(StepEntry.class).equalTo("date", date).findFirst();
```

If there is an object in the database with the given date (`date.getTime()` is the same as for the date in the database) then it works.

Answer (score 2):

Realm also compare miliseconds, but in `Date` object we can only set to `second`.
So when I create `Date` object, I use `Calendar` for set millisecond to 0

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, anyTime);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, anyTime);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
date.setTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

It will help me compare the time that I input with the time in database.
Thank @Christian Melchior so much for your supporting